# An illegal reflective access operation warning

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I am making a javafx application with gradle, but it gives me WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred when I start it as a jar and a InaccessibleObjectException when I start it as a gradle task:

```
Jar:
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil (file:/C:/Users/i/Downloads/fda.das.main.jar) to field javafx.scene.image.Image.url
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Gradle task:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.String javafx.scene.image.Image.url accessible: module javafx.graphics does not "opens javafx.scene.image" to unnamed module @717d2ad8
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:176)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:170)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.checkAndFixAccess(ClassUtil.java:914)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.fixAccess(FieldProperty.java:102)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBuilder._fixAccess(BeanDeserializerBuilder.java:484)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBuilder.build(BeanDeserializerBuilder.java:350)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:246)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:137)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:411)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findNonContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:467)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:473)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:477)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4190)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4009)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at Helpers.Services.LoginService$1.call(LoginService.java:59)
    at Helpers.Services.LoginService$1.call(LoginService.java:32)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1425)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$executeTask$6(Service.java:725)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$executeTask$7(Service.java:724)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

When I run it from intellij everything works fine. I tried adding "--add-opens", "java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED" in my gradle.build both after the plugin and in the run{}, but it didn't fix it:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}
apply plugin: 'application'
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["--add-opens", "java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED"]

run {
    main = 'Application.RestaurantApplication'
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["--add-opens", "java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED"]

}

group 'fda'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'com.1stleg', name: 'jnativehook', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.6.1'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.8'


}
javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.media' ]
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong here and why loader unnamed is not working?

My javaFX code is a service that is requesting user login the error is coming when I use the mapper with my json content to create a user model in which there is a javafx Image field:

```
public class LoginService extends Service {
    private final StringProperty username = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "username");
    private final StringProperty password = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "password");
    public final StringProperty usernameProperty() { return username; }
    public final StringProperty passwordProperty() { return password; }

    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        return new Task<User>() {
            @Override
            protected User call() throws Exception {
                Map<String, Object> jsonValues = new HashMap<>();
                jsonValues.put("username", username.get());
                jsonValues.put("password", password.get());
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonValues);

                StringEntity postEntity = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF8");
                postEntity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost( base + "/api/users/login");
                httpPost.setEntity(postEntity);

                try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost)) {

                    int responseStatus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    HttpEntity receivedEntity = response.getEntity();
                    String content = EntityUtils.toString(receivedEntity);

                    if (responseStatus != 200) {
                        EntityUtils.consume(receivedEntity);
                        throw new HttpException(content);
                    }

                    String jwtToken = response.getHeaders("Authorization")[0].getValue();

                    User user = mapper.readValue(content, User.class); //Here
                    ServerRequests.userPreference.put(String.valueOf(user.getId()), jwtToken);

                    EntityUtils.consume(receivedEntity);

                    return mapper.readValue(content, User.class);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And my model:

```
package Models;


import javafx.scene.image.Image;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class User {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private String country;
    private String role;
    private String profilePicture;
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    private Image image;

    private Map<Integer, Order> orders = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public User(){

    }

    public User(int id, String username, String firstName, String lastName, int age, String country, String role, String profilePicture, Restaurant restaurant) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.country = country;
        this.role = role;
        this.profilePicture = profilePicture;
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getProfilePicture() {
        return profilePicture;
    }

    public void setProfilePicture(String profilePicture) {
        this.profilePicture = profilePicture;
    }

    public Restaurant getRestaurant() {
        return restaurant;
    }

    public void setRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(Map<Integer, Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: --add-opens is the right direction - but simply translate the error message exactly like it is (not what you deduct from the stacktrace): _module javafx.graphics does not "opens javafx.scene.image" to unnamed module_ translates into `--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image=ALL_UNNAMED`

Comment: @kleopatra oh lol I tried with javafx.scene thinking that it will include the image class and it didn't work, but with scene.image it works. Thanks!!